# How to Convert WSDL to Java Object

Tags: wsdl2java

Hi I am working with SOAP service and i just want to know that how can i convert WSDL to java object. Is their any Open source API in Java which will Parse it. Please share the working example.

Answer (score 0):

As we invoke the WSDL2Java using commandline or via plugins. So we can do same thing by calling the main class of the same plugin from java class.

For eg. if you are using apache cxf plugin. Then just add plugin jars to classpath and invoke main class ie. org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava and provide the neccessary inputs like wsdl file location in String[] args as input to main method. You can get details of possible input for this plugin from this [URL](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html)

I have not tried this but i feel this is doable. :)